# COM on Windows7 and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, com, registration

I registered a COM dll (under administrator) using regsvr32, which I want to use in Visual Studio 2008 (under administrator) for my project in **Windows 7**. Now, when I try to use the interfaces and classes from the COM, then I can't see any of the methods. When I use the object browser to view the COM classes, then I can see that they are all empty. However when I use the same COM on **windows XP** using VS2008, then all methods are suddenly available. Does anybody know why this is happening and how to get this working under Windows 7?

Comment: is your windows 7 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the com object that I have been using. Its not supported to work in Win7.